# F# - Reflection, Pattern matching: GetValue

Tags: f#

```
| P.Call(_, mi, [P.Value(value, _); P.PropertyGet(q, propInfo, [])]) -> ...
```

How would I use the `GetValue` method, in order to get the value for `propInfo`?

**EDIT**

Based on @Stephen Swensen' suggestion, I've tried to do:

```
| P.Call(_, mi, [P.Value(value, _); P.PropertyGet(q, pi, [])]) ->
    match q.Value with
    | P.PropertyGet(_, pi2, []) -> printfn "%A" <| pi.GetValue(pi2, null)
    | _ -> failwith "fail"
```

However, it simply throws an exception:

> TargetException was unhandled: Object
>   does not match target type.

The value of `pi2` at runtime is: `Some({PropertyGet (None, Author r, [])})`

**EDIT**

Bahh... didnt notice that `pi2` is static.

The solution is:

```
| P.Call(_, mi, [P.Value(value, _); P.PropertyGet(q, pi, [])]) ->
    match q.Value with
    | P.PropertyGet(_, pi2, []) -> 
        let getObj = pi2.GetValue(null, null)
        printfn "%A" <| pi.GetValue(getObj, null)
    | _ -> failwith "fail"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what kind of property it is (static or instance) and whether or not it takes any arguments.

Based on your pattern match it looks like your property doesn't take any arguments, so we'll put that aside.

If it is a static property, then `q` is `None` and you just need to call `propInfo.GetValue(null, null)`.

If it is an instance property, then `q` is `Some(instance)` where `instance` is type `Expr`.  That presents a problem. You need to be able to convert the expression to value you can pass as the first argument to `GetValue`. But if the expression is arbitrarily complex, that would require a lot of work to implement an expression evaluator.

Comment: It's an instance property. By doing `propInfo.GetValue(instance, null)` it throws an exception: TargetException was unhandled: Object does not match target type. Any suggestions? - Just a little side note, I'm passing in a `'a list` not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ebb: right, I got ahead of myself, I updated my answer after realizing that `instance` is an `Expr` representing the instance and not the value of the instance itself.

Comment: @ebb: I'm not sure what you mean regarding "passing in a `'a list`".

Comment: please see my updated post. - Forget about the `'a list` thing, its not relevant - my mistake.